# utf-8 encoding works in iPython console, not in Spyder editor

Tags: python, utf-8, spyder

here is the minimal test. in Spyder Editor, I wrote these 4 lines (nothing else)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding() )
print(u"µ")
```

I get :

```
utf-8
Âµ
```

but if I just copy-paste the 2 lines in iPython console, I get

[image: utf-8 \n µ]

what's wrong with my .py file or with spyder Editor?

Comment: Which version of Python? (aka, why the `u"..."`?). Are you sure you are not doing a copy/paste error (so adding an invisible character (like colours))?

Comment: The file could also be saved in other enconding than `utf-8`, which is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried at home (I mean, on another computer), with Spyder 4.1.5, I did not reproduce this problem.
The file has been created within spyder, so I guess it is in utf-8. The first line "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" was already there.

Comment: My Python version : 3.7.6, Spyder 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

> what's wrong with my .py file or with spyder Editor?

The problem is most likely that you're using Windows and the console interprets your output as Windows-1252 (the default console encoding for western european windows):

```py
>>> 'µ'.encode('utf-8').decode('windows-1252')
'Âµ'
```

It's not clear whether the first snippet is the spyder console or a normal `python` shell in the windows console.

> ```
> print(sys.getdefaultencoding() )
> ```

has literally nothing to do with anything. `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is the internal python encoding.

You can try to mess with `PYTHONIOENCODING`, or see what `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns.

Comment: In spyder Editor, when I press F5, it execute the file into the iPython console (which is also shown in Spyder GUI).
I test the same code (copy-pasted) directly into the iPython console, and I don't get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, thanks to @Carlos Cordoba (Spyder's master).

I opened the file in **notepad++**, and converted it into "**UTF-8 BOM**" (it was in UTF-8 but without BOM)

Now it works